# text jumping around because of javascript loading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using zurb's foundation to build a website, which uses the slider quite heavily. Everything is functioning currently ( without optimizing, fixing responsive errors etc ), except for a usability issue with the way the site loads.

When I load the site, the image for the slideshows load after the content is there, so there's a bit of an ugly jumping of all the text. You can see the effect by visiting the development server -- 
http://www.dentasignclients.com/opo2

How would I make it so that the text stays in place? I tried loading all the javascript in the  tag, but that didn't change the results.

It's okay if the images load after, as long as the text doesn't alter it's position. Sort of like having some sort of invisible placeholder.

Do you know what I would do to make the loading of the site cleaner?

Comment: works for me in google chrome, full fail in konqueror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People always seem to forget the basics...

You need to have a `width` and `height` attribute on the `<img>` element to create the appropriate placeholder area.

[This is even part of the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes)

Comment: Except if you look at the site, it is not an `<img>` tag, but a `<div>` with a `background-image` defined...

Comment: GregL is onto something :). One problem I face with defining the width and height though is because of the responsive design. If I define a height, won't it negate the responsiveness of things?

Comment: @StepanParunashvili in that case what you have to do is use width/height based on the viewport (possibly using a percentage). The `<img>` width/height attributes may not help in that case since those are based on pixels.

Comment: This was the error, though Foundation doesn't allow setting height on the orbit slider. I ended up using another solution ( Search Camera Responsive Slider -- the child of the free diapo slider )

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine in Google chrome. However, I had the exact same issue when I was building a site a while ago. The text jumped around and random divs would jump around (despite setting heights wherever possible). It was a headache and I debugged for days. Like you, I was also using jQuery UI 1.8.2. I upgraded to jQuery UI 1.9.2 and that seemed to fix all problems of strange jumping and weird animations. It could be a bug. Try changing your version of jQuery UI and see if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" </script>
```